# View all collections in the browser console

Tags: meteor, ddp

I would like to know how to list all collections of Meteor app in a browser.

Basically, I need to use an undocumented DDP connection to some host, and need to know all collection names.

I'ved tried things like `Meteor.collections`, `Meteor.default_connection.collections` but none of them works. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `_.keys(Meteor.connection._mongo_livedata_collections)`?

Comment: @MasterAM that works. Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Take a look at the answer. It contains a cleaner way of achieving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongo's local_collection_driver updates an object on DDP the connection whenever a collection is created. It can be accessed via `<connection>._mongo_livedata_collections`, and its keys are the names of the collections.

`_.keys(Meteor.connection._mongo_livedata_collections)`

The DDP connection itself manages its stores in an object called `_stores`, and can be accessed similarly via:

`_.keys(Meteor.connection._stores)`

This API is, however, private and undocumented, and may change in the future. A cleaner way would be to use a package that provides such function: [dburles:mongo-collection-instances](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances).

Then, use `Mongo.Collection.getAll()` to get a description of all of the collections, which includes their names.